# Get actual image size, after resizing it React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am fetching images from an API with unknown dimensions.

I would like to be able to know the actual size of the image after the resize process.

```
            <Image 
            style={{ resizeMode: Image.resizeMode.contain}}
            source={{uri:'https://blabla.com/img.jpg'}} 
            />
```

The **Image.resizeMode.contain** is to scale the image uniformly, so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less the corresponding dimension of the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#onlayout)

```
<Image 
    style={{ resizeMode: Image.resizeMode.contain}}
    source={{ uri:'https://blabla.com/img.jpg' }} 
    onLayout={(event) => {
        const { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
        console.log(`Image size: ${width}x${height}`);
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: thanks, it works for me, but you should change last **)** with **}**